# Azure DevOps Private Board and Task Board

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps has good support for Board like Task Board , Backlog etc but some of this thing are public.

- Like TaskBoard is sprint specific so I can not have my own taskboard.

I want to manage my own taskboard without any sprint. Is it possible ?

Is it possible to create bulk task without taskboard or opening task window for each task and create.

Comment: Does my answer work? Please try it and kindly let us know the result. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is it possible to create bulk task without taskboard or opening task window for each task and create.

You could refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops to bulk import work items using CSV files.

The other way is to cyclic call this Rest API: [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to create multiple tasks.

> > I want to manage my own taskboard without any sprint. Is it possible ?

I am afraid that it is impossible now. [Taskboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-boards-plans?view=azure-devops#kanban-and-taskboards) track tasks defined for a sprint and you monitor the flow via the sprint burndown chart. It is by design. And you could follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/customize-taskboard?view=azure-devops) to customize a sprint Taskboard.
If you prefer this feature, you could create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.